# On prime ideals in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Consider the ideals $I=(X^4+4X^3+6,X-1)$ and $J=(X^4+4X^3+6,3)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]=(\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})[X]$. 
> Are $I$ and $J$ prime ideals in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$?

Attempt: For the ideal $I$ I tried using a trick that I saw in another post stating that I could reduce $I$ modulo $X\equiv 1$, because then $X^4+4X^3+6\equiv 11\equiv 0 \mod 11$.
Meaning that $I=(X-1)=(X+10)$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$, meaning that it is also prime. Thus $I$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$. My first question is, is this a correct approach?

Now if I would be trying to see if $J$ was prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ then I would usually reduce $X^4+4X^3+6$ modulo $3$ and see if it is irreducible and from there we could come to a conclusion, but we're not working in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ so I don't know if I can still apply this same technique in $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$. I could note that $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ is a field, thus $\mathbb{F}_{11}[X]$ is a PID, so that could help but apart from that I'm clueless.

Any help is greatly appricieted!

Comment: I think the first part is right,  because $x-1$ divides $x^4+4x^3+6.$  On $J$, try finding the gcd.  If it's prime you're done.  I suspect $J$ may be the whole ring.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a thing that if you have an ideal say $(f,g)$ for $f,g\in R[X]$ (with $R$ a ring), and the $\text{gcd}(f,g)=p$ is prime then your ideal is prime as well?

Comment: As $J$ contains the unit $3$ it must be the whole ring.

Comment: Yes, that's a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Bbb Z_{11}$ is a field (so as you said $\Bbb Z_{11}[X]$ is a PID), you can easily see that
\begin{gather*}
I=\langle X^4+4X^3+6,X−1\rangle=\langle \gcd((X^4+4X^3+6,X−1)\rangle,\\
J=\langle X^4+4X^3+6,3\rangle=\langle \gcd(X^4+4X^3+6,3)\rangle.
\end{gather*}
From there, you can examine whether the generators of $I$ and $J$ are irreducible polynomials over your field, which tells us whether $I$ and $J$ are maximal ideals, and thus prime.

However, observe that $3\in \langle X^4+4X^3+6,3\rangle$ and $3\in U(\Bbb Z_{11}[X])$, where $U(\Bbb Z_{11}[X])$ is the group of units of the ring $\Bbb Z_{11}[X]$. Therefore, $J=\Bbb Z_{11}[X]$ and thus it is not prime.